# Resize and computed height - bugs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">

body {
    text-align: center;
}

#prob {
    background-color: #F00;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#prob img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'http://galerijauspomena.net76.net/images/10042011744.jpg';

    var div = $("#prob").get()[0];
    alert($(window).height()); // First showing good height, but few px larger than a page
    document.getElementById("cont").style.lineHeight = $(document).height() + 'px';

    $(window).resize(
        function(){
            alert($(document).height()); // On resize down or up, its showing always bigger px, even on Firefox freeze browser!
            document.getElementById("cont").style.lineHeight = $(document).height() + 'px';
        }
    );
    div.appendChild(img);

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cont">&nbsp; <!-- nbsp in order to line-height to work. Is it any way without it? -->
<div id="prob">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

After resizing, I found that computed height is always bigger, although I do resize down or up. Am I making some mistakes?

Also, on resize, Firefox freeze it self...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do, you want to use `$(window).height()` and not `document`.  The problem is that increasing the line-height would increase the size of the document, which would then increase the line-height, increasing the document size, etc.  So it would just keep getting bigger and bigger.

Comment: That's solved my problem. Is there any way without those nbsp in order to vertical alignment to work?